# UWP DeviceInformation.GetAqsFilterFromDeviceClass AccessViolationException - Why?

Tags: uwp

I am getting the exception when calling the method for any of the enumeration values.  Yet the GetDeviceSelector methods ( e.g Print3DDevice.GetDeviceSelector(); ) all work fine.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Tony

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Can you provide sample code of what your are doing?